# ERROR: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY while creating work order share records

Tags: apex, community, apex-managed-sharing

I am trying to create share records for `workorder` when `workorder` record gets created by community user (`profile:Customer Community User(custom)` and `user license:Customer Community Login`).

Below code that gets executed when record is created. Owner of the record is the logged in community user. `recId` will the record id and `territoryId` will be the territory Id that it should be shared to. These values are getting populated correctly.
Also, the class is defined as `global without sharing class`, so it should be running in system context.

```
workordershare newShareRecord = new workordershare();
newShareRecord .put('AccessLevel','Edit');
newShareRecord .put('ParentId',recId);
newShareRecord .put('RowCause','Manual');
newShareRecord .put('UserOrGroupId',territoryId);
insert newShareRecord ;
```

This throws out error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross- 
reference id: []
```

I tried to run the same code with developer console and it still gave me the same error.I did replace `recId` with workorder record Id and `territoryId` with actual territory id.

However, when I `manually updated the owner of that workorder record to internal user` and then ran the same share record code with dev console, it worked and created share records.

So, now in the apex class, I wrote a code to update workorder `ownerId` to an internal user before it executes share record code.But it continues to give the same error. I can see that `workorder ownerId` has been updated to `internal user`.

I am not able to understand why it is giving error with apex class but not with dev console since both are running in   system context.

Also, when I run the code in dev console, why does it throw error when record owner is a portal user but not when record owner is an internal user.